# Multiplier with counter, displays answers as zero

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a times table counter. It's supposed to output

1 x 5 is 5
2 x 5 is 10
3 x 5 is 15
up to 10 x 5 is 50

The input is the 5, the counter is taken from the i in the for loop.

It's counting through the numbers but I can't get it to calculate the result, and I can't see what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated

Code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = kb.nextInt();
    Math math1 = new Math(0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        math1.setNum2(i);
        math1.multiplier();
        System.out.println(input + " times " + i + " is " + math1.getResult());
    }
} //main

} // class Program
```

and

```
public class Math {

private int num;
private int num2;
private int result;
//constructor//
public Math(int num, int num2){
    this.num = num;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.result = result;
}

//get//
public int getNum(){
    return this.num;
}

public int getNum2(){
    return this.num2;
}

public int getResult(){
    return this.result;
}
//set//
public void setNum(int value){
    this.num = value;
}

public void setNum2(int value){
    this.num2 = value;
}
//other//
public void multiplier(){
    this.num = num;
    result = num * num2;
}
} // class Math
```

Comment: You seem to be multiply everything by zero.  Check the parameters to the math class again.

Comment: never using `input`. Try `Math math1 = new Math(input, 0)`.

Comment: `this.result = result` (in the constructor) without a result parameter... Seems a little bit sketchy...

Comment: you need to call setNum(input) before the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be multiplying times zero no matter what you are doing. `Math math1 = new Math(0,0);` implies something*0. You need to use your input in the code. As arthur mentioned use,  `Math math1 = new Math(input, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You are always multiplying by 0. Hence your result.

Change your code like the following in the main method:

```
 // use the input that you took
 //let's take 5
 Math math1 = new Math(0,0);
 math1.setNum(input);
```

After that make sure you use it in the `Math` class.

Update the constructor:

```
public Math(int num, int num2){
    this.num = num;
    this.num2 = num2;
}
```

`result` has nothing to do here.

But then the question comes, how to get the `result`.

For that change the multiplier method to the following:

```
public void multiplier(){
    this.result = num * num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying everything by 0 mate. You see those parameters you pass into the Math class object.

Try something on the following lines:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = in.nextInt(); // I suppose this is where the user enters the numbers say 5.
Math math = new Math(number, 0);
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
   math.setNum2(i);
   math.multiplier();
   System.out.println(input + " times " + i + " is " + : math.getResult());
}
```

This should get you through.